WPF dataGrid merge cells - visual effect
I have Datagrid in WPF which is already rendered on the UI - I right-click on a DatagridCell and selected MergeDown. I want a visual effect shows 2 cells have been merged - see expected below
I have checked below links but to no avail
Merge Cells in WPF DataGrid
c# wpf datagrid merge cells
Image below shows my requirement and current behaviour and further below my outcome when running the code

Result

How can I achieve this?
XAML:
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"></DataGrid>
    </Grid>
 </Window>

My code :-
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
 using System.Windows;
 using System.Windows.Controls;
 using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
 using System.Windows.Media;

 namespace yourNamespace
 {
 
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {               
    public class YourDataItem
    {
        public string Column1 { get; set; }
        public string Column2 { get; set; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Create a collection of YourDataItem objects
        ObservableCollection<YourDataItem> dataItems =
        [
            // Populate the collection with sample data
            new YourDataItem { Column1 = "1", Column2 = "2"},
            new YourDataItem { Column1 = "3", Column2 = "4"},
            new YourDataItem { Column1 = "5", Column2 = "6"},
        ];

        // Set the collection as the ItemsSource of the DataGrid
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataItems;
        dataGrid.Loaded += DataGrid_Loaded;
    }

    private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;

        // Add context menu to each cell in the DataGrid
        foreach (var row in GetDataGridRows(dataGrid))
        {
            foreach (DataGridCell cell in GetVisualChildren<DataGridCell>(row))
            {
                cell.ContextMenu = CreateContextMenu(cell);
            }
        }
    }

    private ContextMenu CreateContextMenu(DataGridCell cell)
    {
        var contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

        // Merge Right menu item
        //var mergeRightMenuItem = new MenuItem { Header = "Merge Right" };
        //mergeRightMenuItem.Click += (sender, e) => MergeCells(cell, mergeRight: true, mergeDown: false);
       //contextMenu.Items.Add(mergeRightMenuItem);

        // Merge Down menu item
        var mergeDownMenuItem = new MenuItem { Header = "Merge Down" };
        mergeDownMenuItem.Click += (sender, e) => MergeCells(cell, mergeRight: false, mergeDown: true);
        contextMenu.Items.Add(mergeDownMenuItem);

        return contextMenu;
    }

    private void MergeCells(DataGridCell cell, bool mergeRight, bool mergeDown)
    {
        var dataGrid = FindVisualParent<DataGrid>(cell);
        if (dataGrid == null)
            return;

        var rowIndex = GetDataGridRowIndex(cell);
        var columnIndex = GetDataGridColumnIndex(cell);


        if (mergeRight && columnIndex < dataGrid.Columns.Count - 1)
        {
            if (mergeRight && columnIndex < dataGrid.Columns.Count - 1)
            {
                //TODO
            }
        }

        if (mergeDown && rowIndex < dataGrid.Items.Count - 1)
        {
            var nextRow = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex + 1);

            if (nextRow != null)
            {
                var currentRow = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex);
                if (currentRow != null)
                {
                    Grid.SetRowSpan(cell, 2);
                    cell.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 0);
                    
                   // Hide only the specific cell in the next row
                    var nextCell = GetCellFromRowAndColumn(dataGrid, rowIndex + 1, columnIndex);
                    var currentCell = GetCellFromRowAndColumn(dataGrid, rowIndex, columnIndex);

                    if (nextCell != null)
                    {
                        nextCell.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                        nextCell.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
                        currentCell.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
       
    }               

    private DataGridCell? GetCellFromRowAndColumn(DataGrid dataGrid, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
        if (rowIndex < 0 || rowIndex >= dataGrid.Items.Count || columnIndex < 0 || columnIndex >= dataGrid.Columns.Count)
            return null;

        var row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex);
        if (row == null)
        {
            // If the row is not generated yet, force it to be generated
            dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(dataGrid.Items[rowIndex]);
            dataGrid.UpdateLayout();
            row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex);
        }

        if (row != null)
        {
            var presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
            if (presenter != null)
            {
                var cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(columnIndex);
                return cell;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private T? GetVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (child is T typedChild)
            {
                return typedChild;
            }

            var foundChild = GetVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (foundChild != null)
            {
                return foundChild;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private IEnumerable<DataGridRow> GetDataGridRows(DataGrid grid)
    {
        var itemsSource = grid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
        if (itemsSource == null) yield break;

        foreach (var item in itemsSource)
        {
            var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
            if (row != null) yield return row;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<T> GetVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (parent != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                if (child is T typedChild)
                {
                    yield return typedChild;
                }

                foreach (var nestedChild in GetVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return nestedChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private int GetDataGridRowIndex(DataGridCell cell)
    {
        var row = FindVisualParent<DataGridRow>(cell);
        if (row != null)
        {
            return row.GetIndex();
        }
        return -1; // If the row index cannot be determined
    }

    private int GetDataGridColumnIndex(DataGridCell cell)
    {
        if (cell.Column != null)
        {
            return cell.Column.DisplayIndex;
        }
        return -1; // If the column index cannot be determined
    }

    private T FindVisualParent<T>(DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

        if (parentObject == null)
            return null;

        if (parentObject is T parent)
            return parent;

        return FindVisualParent<T>(parentObject);
    }
}

}

You might want to not use a datagrid for this. Does it have to be a DataGrid? It's going to take a lot of time and always be a little janky. I would seriously suggest using an ItemsControl with custom controls in it or a DataTemplate with your custom rows in it and a ListBox that holds it in the ItemTemplate.

Maybe that can help https://github.com/Henka-Programmer/XTable

Alternatively, you can set a custom Attached Property to a cell, in which an Adorner will be attached to it, overlapping it and the neighboring cell.

It has to be a dataGrid at the moment, @EldHasp - I will look further into your suggestion, thanks

A Grid with TextBlocks or TextBoxes is the equivalent of  a "DataGrid". To "merge cells" you can "extend" a TextBlock / Box over any number of rows and or columns. Center aligning the text finishes off the "illusion" (which is what it's all about). Border controls with sides or no sides and different strokes can add to the effect.
